# ParallelEnumerable.WithDegreeOfParallelism() not restricting tasks?

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5

I'm attempting to use AsParallel() with async-await to have an application process a series of tasks in parallel, but with a restricted degree of concurrency due to the task starting an external Process that has significant memory usage (hence wanting to wait for the process to complete before proceeding to the next item in the series).  Most literature I've seen on the function [ParallelEnumerable.WithDegreeOfSeparation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests that using it will set a max limit on concurrent tasks at any one time, but my own tests seem to suggest that it's skipping the limit altogether.

To provide an rough example (WithDegreeOrParallelism() set to 1 deliberately to demonstrate the issue):

```
public class Example
{
    private async Task HeavyTask(int i)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10 * 1000);
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        int n = 0;

        await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                                     .AsParallel()
                                     .WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)
                                     .Select(async i =>
                                     {
                                         Interlocked.Increment(ref n);
                                         Console.WriteLine("[+] " + n);

                                         await HeavyTask(i);

                                         Interlocked.Decrement(ref n);
                                         Console.WriteLine("[-] " + n);
                                     }));
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await new Example().Run();
        }).Wait();
    }
}
```

From what I understand, the code above is meant to produce output along the lines of:

```
[+] 1
[-] 0
[+] 1
[-] 0
...
```

But instead returns:

```
[+] 1
[+] 2
[+] 3
[+] 4
...
```

Suggesting that it starting off all the tasks in the list and then waiting for the tasks to return.

Is there anything particularly obvious (or non-obvious) that I'm doing wrong which is making it seem like WithDegreeOfParallelism() is being ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Sorry, after testing your code i understand what you are seeing now

```
async i =>
```

Async lambda is just `async void`, basically unobserved task which will run regardless `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` will show you clearly it is consuming as many threads as it likes

Also note, if your heavy task is IO bound, then skip the `PLINQ` and `Parallel` use `async` and `await` in an TPL Dataflow `ActionBlock` as it will give you the best of both worlds

**E.g**

```
public static async Task DoWorkLoads(List<Something> results)
{
   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                     {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
                     };

   var block = new ActionBlock<int>(MyMethodAsync, options);

   foreach (var item in list)
      block.Post(item );

   block.Complete();
   await block.Completion;

}

...

public async Task MyMethodAsync(int i)
{       
    await Task.Delay(10 * 1000);
}
```

**Original**

This is very subtle and a very common misunderstanding, however the documentation i think seems wrong

> Sets the degree of parallelism to use in a query. Degree of
>   parallelism is the **maximum** number of concurrently executing tasks that
>   will be used to process the query.

Though if we dig into this a bit more we get a better understanding, also there are github conversations on this as well.

[ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism vs PLINQ’s WithDegreeOfParallelism](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/05/29/paralleloptions-maxdegreeofparallelism-vs-plinqs-withdegreeofparallelism/)

> PLINQ is different.  Some important Standard Query Operators in PLINQ
>   require communication between the threads involved in the processing
>   of the query, including some that rely on a Barrier to enable threads
>   to operate in lock-step.  The PLINQ design requires that a specific
>   number of threads be actively involved for the query to make any
>   progress.  **Thus when you specify a DegreeOfParallelism for PLINQ,
>   you’re specifying the actual number of threads that will be involved,
>   rather than just a maximum**.